# opengl black artifacts between meshes

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, libgdx

I am doing a little something using libgdx and opengl es 2. I use mesh to draw a table. A mesh mirrored around x and y axis four times to create four parts of a table.
The problem is on some devices there is a black line between these meshes. In some other devices it is all good. I also need to mention that if the view port is perpendicular to the surface of the table - viewing from the top- , the artifacts are not visible. I enabled DITHERing with no effect. I tried to use multisampling, but that didn't make any difference either, or I didn't do it right.
I attached a screen grab of the rendered artifact.
I can send the code, but I am not sure which part might be of interest. Please help?

[image]

Comment: How many triangles does the mesh consist of? Does it have a z-component?

Comment: It has a z component. I am not sure about the number of triangles, but is is not big number. Like every quad surface has two, and this middle section two on each part, if you know what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a z-fighting artifact. You better use a single, combined table mesh with vertices of all its 4 parts welded together.

Comment: Wouldn't a green polygon and a green polygon z- fighting cause green pixels?

Comment: Because of lack of precision you still can see imperfect rasterisation of edges. I believe, what you see is either black clear color or some black geometry behind table. You can try to put some brightly colored geometry behind table planes to check if you can 'see through' there black lines. If you do, then you have z-fighting caused by lack of z-buffer precision.

Comment: Wireframe screenshot may help. Could you please provide it too? I suppose you may have T- or Y- geometry junctions in one vertex.

Comment: I don't see how putting a different color geometry behind it proves that it's z-fighting. If it changes color it could still be something different. I think disabling depth testing would be a more conclusive way to test your theory.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I will try them out. One thing I noticed is that they are visible when the view point is in one side of table, but when I rotate the view to the other side, there are not visible. So it doesn't look quite like z fighting. I am not sure though